# Spring boot docker testcontainers keep starting new containers on VDS

Tags: spring-boot, docker, ubuntu, testcontainers

So i have issued with very strange problem, I use testcontainers to start app and database instance while testing. On my pc (Mac), on my second pc which has Windows and even on computer with Ubuntu everything works as expected.

Then I started to use github actions to initiate tests every time someone tries to make merge request to master branch. And here I have problem.

I will skip github actions code part because It won't pass tests even with basic `gradlew test clean` command.

So behavior I expect:

1. I write `gradlew test clean`
2. Spring starts application container and database container. (And it works everywhere except my VDS, where it must work)

What behavior I get on VDS:

1. I write `gradlew test clean`
2. Spring starts application container and database container.
3. Spring for some reason can't connect to database container and starts another database container (timeout 2 minutes)
4. During tests Spring creates 4-5 database containers and without any success to connect with them fails all tests (as expected without working DB)

Every test file has following database configuration:

```
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
@Testcontainers
@ContextConfiguration(initializers = {UserDataControllerTest.Initializer.class})
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation.class)
class UserDataControllerTest {

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mockMvc;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper objectMapper;

    @ClassRule
    @Container
    public final static MySQLContainer mysqlContainer = new MySQLContainer("mysql:8.0");

... some tests

    static class Initializer
            implements ApplicationContextInitializer<ConfigurableApplicationContext> {
        public void initialize(ConfigurableApplicationContext configurableApplicationContext) {
            TestPropertyValues.of(
                    "spring.datasource.url=" + mysqlContainer.getJdbcUrl(),
                    "spring.datasource.username=" + mysqlContainer.getUsername(),
                    "spring.datasource.password=" + mysqlContainer.getPassword(),
                    "spring.jpa.generate-ddl=true",
                    "spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop"
            ).applyTo(configurableApplicationContext.getEnvironment());
        }
    }
}
```

Stacktrace I get after command finishes:

```
org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Container startup failed
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:336)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.start(GenericContainer.java:317)
    at app//org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.start(TestcontainersExtension.java:242)
    at app//org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension$StoreAdapter.access$200(TestcontainersExtension.java:229)
    at app//org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$null$1(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.lambda$getOrComputeIfAbsent$4(ExtensionValuesStore.java:86)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.computeValue(ExtensionValuesStore.java:223)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$MemoizingSupplier.get(ExtensionValuesStore.java:211)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.evaluate(ExtensionValuesStore.java:191)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore$StoredValue.access$100(ExtensionValuesStore.java:171)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.ExtensionValuesStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(ExtensionValuesStore.java:89)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.NamespaceAwareStore.getOrComputeIfAbsent(NamespaceAwareStore.java:53)
    at app//org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.lambda$beforeAll$2(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.testcontainers.junit.jupiter.TestcontainersExtension.beforeAll(TestcontainersExtension.java:59)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeBeforeAllCallbacks$10(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeBeforeAllCallbacks(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:381)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:205)
    at app//org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.before(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:80)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:148)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57)
    at app//org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:108)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:96)
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.processAllTestClasses(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:99)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor$CollectAllTestClassesExecutor.access$000(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:79)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.junitplatform.JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.stop(JUnitPlatformTestClassProcessor.java:75)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.SuiteTestClassProcessor.stop(SuiteTestClassProcessor.java:61)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base@17.0.4/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base@17.0.4/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ContextClassLoaderDispatch.dispatch(ContextClassLoaderDispatch.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at jdk.proxy1/jdk.proxy1.$Proxy2.stop(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker$3.run(TestWorker.java:193)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.executeAndMaintainThreadName(TestWorker.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.testing.worker.TestWorker.execute(TestWorker.java:60)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.ActionExecutionWorker.execute(ActionExecutionWorker.java:56)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:133)
    at org.gradle.process.internal.worker.child.SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.call(SystemApplicationClassLoaderWorker.java:71)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.run(GradleWorkerMain.java:69)
    at app//worker.org.gradle.process.internal.worker.GradleWorkerMain.main(GradleWorkerMain.java:74)
Caused by: org.rnorth.ducttape.RetryCountExceededException: Retry limit hit with exception
    at app//org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:88)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.doStart(GenericContainer.java:329)
    ... 69 more
Caused by: org.testcontainers.containers.ContainerLaunchException: Could not create/start container
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:525)
    at app//org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.lambda$doStart$0(GenericContainer.java:331)
    at app//org.rnorth.ducttape.unreliables.Unreliables.retryUntilSuccess(Unreliables.java:81)
    ... 70 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Container is started, but cannot be accessed by (JDBC URL: jdbc:mysql://localhost:49156/test), please check container logs
    at org.testcontainers.containers.JdbcDatabaseContainer.waitUntilContainerStarted(JdbcDatabaseContainer.java:165)
    at org.testcontainers.containers.GenericContainer.tryStart(GenericContainer.java:468)
    ... 72 more
```

PS. I multiple times reinstalled OS on VDS, there was Debian and now Ubuntu. Docker was installed by the instruction on the official website, user which starts github actions added to docker group (it actually doesn't matter because it won't start even from root user)

Comment: `@Container` and `@Testcontainers` are from JUnit 5 and `@ClassRule` is from Junit 4. Also, revist `@Test` in order to use the right one.

Comment: The bottom message of the posted stacktrace recommends to check the mysql container logs. Have you tried to do this? You can redirect container logs to your test logs using this testcontainers feature: https://www.testcontainers.org/features/container_logs/

Comment: @EddúMeléndez, I found out that testcontainers runs very slow on this particular server, so after increasing the timeout App container waits for mysql container to startup everything works well. It's very strange because this server is the most powerful machine of all the ones I have tried

Comment: I am guessing your root password for mysql is not up to the mysql password policy. Did you check logs of dead db container?